# Netrw - Lexplore is not an editor command

Tags: vimrc, netrw

I was trying to configure vim to have a file explorer on the side with no plugins. I found the following script:

```
function! ToggleNetrw()
  if g:NetrwIsOpen
    let i = bufnr("$")
    while (i >= 1)
        if(getbufvar(i,"&filetype") == "netrw")
            silent exe "bwipeout " . i
        endif
        let i-=1
    endwhile
    let g:NetrwIsOpen=0
 else
    let g:NetrwIsOpen=1
    silent Lexplore
 endif
endfunction
```

I have barely written any vimrc code so I'm not 100% sure what this function does, but from my understanding this should open Netrw if it isn't already open and do nothing if it is.

However I'm getting the following error message when the vimrc folder is re-initialized:

```
Not an editor command :Lexplore
```

Does this have something to do with my vim version, my linux distro (which is CentOS) or something else?

Comment: Does `Lexplore` work when you run it manually from the command line?

Comment: No, it returns the same error message

Comment: Okay, that's weird. Everyone should have that. Try it after launching vim with flag `--clean`.

Comment: Returns `unknown option argument: '--clean'`

Comment: How old of a version of Vim is this? And is it actually Vim or is it vi?

Comment: Oh, didn't expect an older version when I installed it. It's 7.4. Also, it's vim

Comment: Yeah, that's about 8 years old I think. I don't know if netrw was a default inclusion for that version. Regardless an upgrade would be of great benefit. :)

Comment: Yeah, i'll upgrade it and see if it fixes it. If it does i'll answer my question

Comment: @BLayer you were indeed correct, it was the version. I answered the question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the version of Vim installed on my system (7.4). At that time, `Netrw` might not have been a default inclusion with Vim.

I didn't know at the time, but the official repositories of CentOS don't yet have the latest version of vim. Once i installed it using this guide: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-vim-centos-7 (version 8.2), i got `Lexplore` working